# While doing client server connection i am geting this error TNS-12535

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, client

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 13-DEC-2016 16:57:44

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
D:\app\jayraj\product\11.2.0\client_3\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(Host = 192.168.158.131)(Port = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLDBCA
)))

TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out

C:\Users\jayraj>
```

Comment: To avoid downvotes on your question you should say what you've tried to fix the problem and compose your post in such a way that it asks an actual question. Take a quick look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the listener is set up consistent with the connection settings in TNSNAMES.

Is the listener started ?

Ping the server to check you can reach it.

Can you get to the database while connected to the server ?

Do you have a firewall that might get in the way ?

Is port 1521 open ?

There are lots of reasons why you can get a TNS time out error - some are Oracle components and some are network configuration.
Try starting at each end and working inwards, i.e. verify everything on your client is OK, check everything on the server is correct then make sure the network is configured to allow connections.